# Can 'split' be used?

Tags: java, split

I get this error "cannot resolve symbol method ‘split’ (java lang string)", when I try using the code below.

What could be causing the "split" error?
What is required to use "split" do I need to import android?

```
public void run() {
 byte[] buffer = new byte[2048]; 
 int mybytes;
 String fields[];

 while (true) {
    try {

        mybytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
        String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, mybytes);
        System.out.print("|mybytes|:\t" + mybytes);
        fields = mybytes.split(" ");
        heat = Integer.parseInt(fields[1]);
        speed = Integer.parseInt(fields[3]);
```

Comment: Yes you can Use it. But mybytes is declared as int not as string.

Comment: To be clear, this has nothing to do with Android. This is a Java question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to Declare Your **`mybytes`** as **`String`** not as a **`int`** change it

Use this

```
String mybytes;
```

Instead of this

```
int mybytes;
```

Comment: mbytes is the length. I think the poster wants to split the buffer.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts may be but the OP didn't mention about it

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `split` an `int`. Instead, use a `String`, like :

```
String mybytes;
mybytes = String.valueOf(mmInStream.read(buffer));
fields = mybytes.split(" ");
```

Or you can use

```
fields = readMessage.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to perform a split on an int, not a stream, change the line

```
fields = mybytes.split(" ");
```

to

```
fields = readMessage.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend to split `buffer`, not `mbytes`